# How does std::sort_heap break the heap property?

Tags: c++, sorting, heapsort

[cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort_heap) says:

> The resulting range no longer has the heap property.

[cplusplus.com](https://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort_heap/) says:

> The range loses its properties as a heap.

What do they mean? It sorts, and sorted implies heap, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list sorted ascending is automatically a min-heap. A list sorted descending is automatically a max-heap. `std::sort_heap` turns a max heap into a list sorted ascending, which is no longer a max-heap (but it is a min-heap). To reiterate: the subtlety is that the ordering is being reversed. The list is turned from "weakly descending" (max-heap) to ascending (sorted, not a max-heap).